# Symbol lookup error at runtime even though nm reports symbol present

Tags: c++, undefined, linker-errors, nm

I build my program like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 myprog.cpp -o myprog -lqpid-proton-cpp
```

Then I run `./myprog` and get this error:

```
symbol lookup error: ./myprog: undefined symbol: _ZN6proton10event_loop6injectESt8functionIFvvEE
```

Yet, nm reports the symbol is present in the library . . .

```
nm -D /usr/lib/libqpid-proton-cpp.so | grep _ZN6proton10event_loop6injectESt8functionIFvvEE
```

. . . yields:

```
000000000002f460 T _ZN6proton10event_loop6injectESt8functionIFvvEE
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you verify, e.g., using `ldd myprog`, that you looked at the correct shared object?

Comment: @Dietmar, no, I didn't. I was unaware of ldd. Running `ldd myprog` revealed to me a different copy of the so. I removed it and now my program works. Thank you very much. Maybe post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you verify, e.g., using `ldd myprog`, that you looked at the correct shared object? There is a chance a different shared object is found.